# saved sqoop job not using time zone of the server

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

The following saved sqoop job is using a timezone not that of the server in which the job is saved.

```
sqoop job --create myjob9 -- import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1234/abc  --check-column LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME --incremental lastmodified --last-value "2015-02-15 19.19.37.000000000" --hive-import --table SIM_UNAUDITED_SALES_TMP --append
```

Last value when the job is executed is 1 hour ahead of the system time. How do I sync the timezone?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following generic-argument in order to set the server timezone:

```
-D mapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=$your_timezone"
```

Be careful to use this  generic argument before calling the job-args. So, you can make it this way:

```
sqoop job -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=$your_timezone" --create myjob9 -- import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1234/abc  --check-column LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME --incremental lastmodified --last-value "2015-02-15 19.19.37.000000000" --hive-import --table SIM_UNAUDITED_SALES_TMP --append
```